# SVG to SWF on Linux?

Tags: linux, vector, flash, svg

Any application or method can export SVG or any vector format to SWF from Ubuntu Linux?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know of any tool that will do this at compile-time, but if a runtime solution is acceptable, you could use [svg-web](http://code.google.com/p/svgweb/) which renders SVG using Flash.

Comment: Thanks, I'm developing vector animations for Flash sites and thought I could use just ubuntu. Greetings!

Comment: A quick Google yields this thing as well: http://gtrebaol.free.fr/doc/svgopen/2008/index.html I've never used it, though, so can't directly endorse it. The demos look good, although I can't seem to find a download link...

Comment: Evidently, it's also possible to embed static SVG content in Flex applications. Here's a demo: http://raghuonflex.wordpress.com/2009/06/10/loading-svg-content-in-flex-apps/ Again, I haven't done this myself so YMMV.